# Add scopes to Google Cloud Service account in Terraform Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, service-accounts

I am managing Google Cloud through Terraform. Terraform Cloud authenticates to GCP, with a Service Account stored in the Terraform Cloud variable `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS`.

When trying to create a BQ table from Google Sheet I am getting the error:

```
Error: googleapi: Error 403: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials., accessDenied
```

And according to several SO questions, I can fix it adding the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive to the service account. However, I only find how to use the scopes in other use cases (i.e https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-auth-drive-scope#bigquery_auth_drive_scope-python), where some kind of programming/CLI is involved, which is not the case of Terraform Cloud.

So how could I add that scope for Terraform Cloud authentication based on the `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` variable?

Comment: Terraform seems to use the application-default-credentials (ADCs) when no service account is supplied.

Try below command to set ADCs with the needed scopes.: (The scopes are copied from the tf file in a previous message.)

**gcloud auth application-default login --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery**

Comment: Create an external table where you require **bigquery.tables.create** permission. Refer to [Required roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-drive#required_roles)

Comment: Hello @Javier Lopez Tomas, Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know the answer below helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Comment: Hello @Javier Lopez Tomas, Please check my **EDIT 2** in the answer, which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Adding OAuth Scopes is not a solution and if possible, would not solve the problem. The problem **must** be solved by either: a) using a different identity with the correct IAM roles; b) adding an IAM role to the service account that authorized Terraform. This is an IAM permission problem and not an OAuth scope problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a permissions issue when you are trying to create a BigQuery table with external data source (spreadsheets) from Terraform. Terraform seems to use the application-default-credentials (ADCs) when no service account is supplied.

If you have other BQ tables that are connected with spreadsheets and changing/adding those works out-of-the-box. Only for this specific resource after executing the below command to set ADCs with the needed scopes (The scopes are copied from the tf file):

```
gcloud auth application-default login --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery
```

Also create an external table where you require `bigquery.tables.create` permission. Refer to [Required roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-drive#required_roles), additionally, you can create an external table in BigQuery for a Drive data source (files in Drive) . The access token requires both `"drive"` and `"bigquery"` scope, otherwise the query will fail with a permission error.

**EDIT1 :**
Refer to [Using Terraform Cloud](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#using-terraform-cloud) :

> Place your credentials in a Terraform Cloud environment variable:
>
> 1. Create an environment variable called `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` in your
>    Terraform Cloud workspace.
> 2. Remove the newline characters from your
>    JSON key file and then paste the credentials into the environment
>    variable value field. You can use the tr command to strip newline
>    characters. `cat key.json | tr -s '\n' ' '`
> 3. Mark the variable as
>    **Sensitive** and click the **Save variable**.

> All runs within the workspace will use the `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` variable to authenticate with Google Cloud
> Platform.

**EDIT2:**

**scopes** - (Optional) The list of OAuth 2.0 scopes requested when generating an access token using the service account key specified in **credentials**. Ensure that the scope of the VM/Cluster is set to or includes `googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`, By default, the following scopes are configured: `googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` and `googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`. Refer to [Authentication Configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#authentication-configuration).

**References:**

1. **3nigm4's** and **vitorc.radi's** answers on [How to authenticate to gcp when using terraform cloud](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/how-to-authenticate-to-gcp-when-using-terraform-cloud/17489).
2. [Yaroslav Markovski's](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/profiles/392318934434-Yaroslav-Markovski), **HashiCorp Help Center** article on [How-to set up Google Cloud (GCP) credentials in Terraform Cloud](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/4406586874387-How-to-set-up-Google-Cloud-GCP-credentials-in-Terraform-Cloud)

Comment: Hello Veera. Thanks for anssering. I am not using Terraform through a CLI, but with Terraform Cloud (as stated in the question, but i'll further clarity it in the body of it), so I have a service account stored in a variable in Terraform Cloud, and I don't use a CLI at all, so I cant add the --scopes argument

Comment: Hello @Javier Lopez Tomas, Please have a look at my edit in the answer. Also refer to similar [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73000253) [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59440068), which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Hello. I am already using the GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS. My question is how to add the scopes to that way of authenticating